# Bind the php logic with the checkout page on the Shopify

Tags: shopify, checkout, shopify-app, shopify-api

In `Shopify` I made a custom app in `php`. And now I need to make logic that will work on the `checkout` page.

In fact, I need to change the UPS delivery price conditionally, which means I need to catch or simulate the event of assigning the delivery price to the product price.

Can please tell me how I can execute my `php` code, written in `index.php`, on the `checkout` page? Or how and where can I link my `php` code to page `checkout`?

There is absolutely no information on this in the shopify documentation! In the `Shopify Dev` documentation, I've seen scripts for `wasm` - https://shopify.dev/apps/checkout/shipping-methods, but that's not what I need.

I hope very much for your help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to subscribe your Store to Shopify Plus. Then, you use the Script Editor to change your Shipping Options and prices. You need no PHP. There is no other way to do it really. If you try, you will have a long, heavy, hard, uphill battle for a hundred hours to make something half-baked. Your choice. Plus is 30 minutes to get it done.